# display comments under each image

Tags: php, sql

I want to display **all the comments** posted under each image from a database.
I tried the following code, but I was able to get **only one comment**, which was the last one posted.

```
$sql1="SELECT user,comment FROM comment_table where imagename=:file";
$q1=array(':file'=>$file);
try {
  $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
  $stmt->execute($q1);
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

  $result= $stmt->fetch();
  $c = $result["comment"];
  $u=$result["user"];

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
}
echo "<tr><td>".$u.":".$c."</td><tr>";
```

Please help needed and appreciated.

Comment: You can also do: while($comment = $stmt->fetch()){echo $comment['comment']}

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `foreach` to print all the comments. Take a read here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

With your code it just shows one comment, so try this:

```
$sql1="SELECT user,comment FROM comment_table where imagename=:file";
                            $q1=array(':file'=>$file);
                            try {
    $stmt   = $pdo->prepare($sql1);
    $stmt->execute($q1);
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$result= $stmt->fetch();

catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Failed to run query: " . $e->getMessage());
}

foreach ($result as $res) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$res["user"].":".$res["comment"]."</td><tr>";
}
```